# Permission denied to procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-apex

I have followed [this post](https://community.oracle.com/message/12904183#12904183) and created a procedure in the database. Then I created a new region in the page I want to view the PDF. In the source I put this:

```
<embed src="#OWNER#.download_my_file?p_file=21" width="500" height="375">
```

21 being one of the ids in the table I specified in the procedure. This is just a fixed value temporarily.

When I view the page, I am greeted by an error:

[image]

> (Access to the procedure named: INGTOCBADB.download_my_file is denied)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add your procedure to the "whitelist" of allowed procedure calls in the function WWV_FLOW_EPG_INCLUDE_MOD_LOCAL in the APEX_xxxxxx schema:

```
create or replace Function wwv_flow_epg_include_mod_local(procedure_name IN VARCHAR2)
return boolean
is
BEGIN
   IF upper(procedure_name) IN (
   'DOWNLOAD_MY_FILE',
   ... other procedures already listed
   )
   THEN
      return TRUE;
   ELSE
      return FALSE;
   END IF;
end wwv_flow_epg_include_mod_local;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me, I really appreciate it.

Do I need to replace 'procedure_name' in both the parameter and the upper function with download_my_file? 

Is there anything else I might need to change to that script? Or can I copy-paste it and be good to go?

Edit: I would like to add that I do not yet have that function in my database.

Comment: No.  You just need to edit the existing function in the APEX schema and add the line `'DOWNLOAD_MY_FILE'` to the list of procedures in the `IN` clause.

Comment: Or you could use an alternative approach described here: https://apexplained.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/avoiding-the-wwv_flow_epg_include_mod_local-function/

Comment: I have added your function to my database (which was non-existent before). This is what it shows in my database:
https://gyazo.com/012593c0c2e012cd49b671f2e66c106c - however, I still get the error. Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be a grant issue?  Is the parsing schema of your app also the owner of the procedure?

Comment: Oh boy, I'm not sure. We're working on the Oracle APEX servers. We've made a schema, we named it INGTOCBADB and that's the only schema we've got access to. All of our information is in there.

If you want, I could give you access to our application?

Comment: Oh no, you won't be able to do this in apex.oracle.com if that's what you mean!  The `wwv_flow_epg_include_mod_local` function belongs to the APEX schema (e.g. APEX_050000) and you won't have access to that.

Comment: Tony, thank you for pointing that out. We won't be able to add that functionality into the program in that case. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

The alternative way is by using an application process. I much prefer that way over enabling public access to a db procedure.

You can find the how to in the blog linked and partly copied below. The blog is by Joel Kallman, director of software development at Oracle and the manager for Apex. This guy is worth listening to.

http://joelkallman.blogspot.be/2014/03/yet-another-post-how-to-link-to.html

I've copied over most of the blog and updated the links to working documentation links.

---

> Firstly, a way **not** to do this is via a PL/SQL procedure that is called
>   directly from a URL.  I see this "solution" commonly documented on the
>   Internet, and in general, it should not be followed.  The default
>   configuration of Oracle Application Express has a white list of entry
>   points, callable from a URL.  For security reasons, you absolutely
>   want to leave this restriction in place and not relax it.  This is
>   specified as the [PlsqlRequestValidationFunction for mod_plsql](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39143/toc.htm#HTMRN324) and
>   [security.disableDefaultExclusionList](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56351_01/doc.30/e56293/config_file.htm#GUID-37AA1468-DCB3-4D8B-868C-1910A0C04D68) for Oracle REST Data Services
>   (nee APEX Listener).  With this default security measure in place, you
>   will not be able to invoke a procedure in your schema from a URL. 
>   Good!
>
> The easiest way to return an image from a URL in an APEX application
>   is either via a RESTful Service or via an On-Demand process.  This
>   blog post will cover the On-Demand process.  It's definitely easier to
>   implement via a RESTful Service, and if you can do it via a RESTful
>   call, that will always be much faster - Kris has a [great example](http://krisrice.blogspot.com/2013/07/using-restful-to-deliver-images-for-apex.html) how
>   to do this. However, one benefit of doing this via an On Demand
>   process is that it will also be constrained by any conditions or
>   authorization schemes that are in place for your APEX application
>   (that is, if your application requires authentication and
>   authorization, someone won't be able to access the URL unless they are
>   likewise authenticated to your APEX application and fully authorized).

1. Navigate to Application Builder -> Shared Components -> Application Items
2. Click Create

   - Name:  FILE_ID
   - Scope:  Application
   - Session State Protection:  Unrestricted
3. Navigate to Application Builder -> Shared Components -> Application Processes
4. Click Create

   - Name: GETIMAGE
   - Point:  On Demand: Run this application process when requested by a page process.
5. Click Next
6. For Process Text, enter the following code:

   ```
   begin
     for c1 in (select *
                from my_image_table
               where id = :FILE_ID) loop
       --
       sys.htp.init;
       sys.owa_util.mime_header( c1.mime_type, FALSE );
       sys.htp.p('Content-length: ' || sys.dbms_lob.getlength( c1.blob_content));
       sys.htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || c1.filename || '"' );
       sys.htp.p('Cache-Control: max-age=3600');  -- tell the browser to cache for one hour, adjust as necessary
       sys.owa_util.http_header_close;
       sys.wpg_docload.download_file( c1.blob_content );

       apex_application.stop_apex_engine;
     end loop;
   end;
   ```

Then, all you need to do is construct a URL in your application which calls this application process, as described in the [Application Express Application Builder Users' Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/comp_val_proc.htm#HTMDB04020).  You could manually construct a URL using [`APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_util.htm#CDEIBCJD), or specify a link in the declarative attributes of a Report Column.  Just be sure to specify a Request of `APPLICATION_PROCESS=GETIMAGE` (or whatever your application process name is).  The URL will look something like:

```
f?p=&APP_ID.:0:&APP_SESSION.:APPLICATION_PROCESS=GETIMAGE:::FILE_ID:<some_valid_id>
```

That's all there is to it.

A few closing comments:

1. Be mindful of the authorization scheme specified for the application process.  By default, the Authorization Scheme will be "Must Not Be Public User", which is normally acceptable for applications requiring authentication.  But also remember that you could restrict these links based upon other authorization schemes too.
2. If you want to display the image inline instead of being downloaded by a browser, just change the Content-Disposition from 'attachment' to 'inline'.
3. A reasonable extension and optimization to this code would be to add a version number to your underlying table, increment it every time the file changes, and then reference this file version number in the URL.  Doing this, in combination with a Cache-Control directive in the MIME header would let the client browser cache it for a long time without ever running your On Demand Process again (and thus, saving your valuable database cycles).
4. Application Processes can also be defined on the page-level, so if you wished to have the download link be constrained by the authorization scheme on a specific page, you could do this too.
5. Be careful how this is used. If you don't implement some form of browser caching, then a report which displays 500 images inline on a page will result in 500 requests to the APEX engine and database, per user per page view! Ouch! And then it's a matter of time before a DBA starts hunting for the person slamming their database and reports that "APEX is killing our database". There is an [excellent explanation of cache headers here](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/).

---

Once again - credits go to Joel Kallman.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is adding entries to the default.xml file so ORDS knows what is white listed

EG

```
<entry key="security.inclusionList">wwv_flow*,f,n,p,q,cust,apex,ADMIN.*</entry>
```